# Firebase analytics MAUs and Google Play store statistics' MAUs has a difference of 4x

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-play-console, firebase-analytics

I am calculating monthly active users using my firebase app events table in BigQuery.

The queries below and the MAUs from the firebase analytics dashboard has around the same numbers with a delta of less than 5%. By MAU from firebase I mean the number 'User activity over past 30 days'

The problem: The MAU from the above query is ~400k whereas the MAUs from the google play console for the same period is 1.8M

Below are the queries I have used to calculate MAUs in BigQuery for the month of December.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id)
FROM `xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.events_*`
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)) = 2023
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month DESC;
```

and

```
Select platform, count(distinct user_pseudo_id) from `xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.events_2023*` where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)) = 12
group by platform;
```

May anyone please tell me the potential reason for such a huge discrepancy?
From the documentation of google play console, the monthly active users is anyone who has opened the app.
According to the firebase GA documentation, the User activity over time shows the number of people who used your app in the past 30 days.
Could there be such a huge difference in opening and using the app?

Could there be a problem of linking firebase analytics with the application?

Thanks a lot in advance. I highly appreciate any help.